# Passing URL from HTML / JSP / ERB / etc to Angular JS

Tags: ajax, url, angularjs

Trying to wire up AngularJS to a Spring MVC app (this part is largely irrelevant) and wondering what is the *Angular way* of passing a URL to the JS controller.

I see a lot of examples (pretty much all of them) with URLs / paths hard coded into the JS file and as a long-time MVC developer, this bothers me

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        $http.get('/someUrl').success(successCallback);
    }
}
```

I understand I could just set a JS variable in my JSP but this doesn't feel like the right way forward.

So what is the *Angular way* of passing URLs from things like `<spring:url>` or Rails' `url_for(:action => 'some_action')` to Angular controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using constants for this which can be injected as dependencies, so for instance:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
      .constant('urls', {
          'saveUrl': '<c:url value="/save"/>',
          'cancelUrl': '<c:url value="/cancel"/>'
      })
      .controller('someController', function($scope, urls) {
            $scope.saveUrl = urls.saveUrl;
        });
```

however, it gets a bit harder if I want to populate some model as well. Not sure how to handle that scenario, allthough for now I have created a config section for each service, that will add the content to it by looping over the spring model. But this might be better done by letting angular perform a submit to a page and get all the data through json call. However that means that the calling page should already be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went with this approach though I'm still very keen to hear from others

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit('<spring:url value="/someUrl" />', myModel)" novalidate>
```

... and this in the controller

```
$scope.submit = function(url, model) { // ...
```